# P/L SQL search query

Tags: plsql, oracle11g

I has p/l sql PROCEDURE that is simple look like bellow
when user didn't enter any search word normally seach_ is get 'ALL' value and i need all data from myTB table

when user enter value as 'abc' i want to return all match 'abc' name from myTB

```
seach_ VARCHAR2(100) :='ALL';

   IF attr_.EXISTS('SEACRH') THEN
      seach_ := attr_('SEACRH');
   END IF;


SELECT * FORM myTB
WHERE (NAME LIKE '%seach_%') OR (seach_ = 'ALL')
```

when user enter some value my select don't return any value what should i do for get expected result?

note: i feel `NAME LIKE '%seach_%'` not work for me

Comment: Remove apostrophes and try again. At this time your query is searching for *%seach_%* instead of *%user_input%*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to concatenate your search value with the wildcards:

```
SELECT * FROM myTB
WHERE seach_ = 'ALL'
OR NAME LIKE '%' || seach_ || '%'
```

You also had `FORM` instead of `FROM`, but as your procedure wouldn't have compiled with that, presumably that was a typo introduced in creating the question.